# Create Route for Work VPN Traffic

Tags: networking, vpn, routing

Ok, so here's the situation.  I consult on several projects, and some require me to connect to their VPN before I can access their servers.  The problem is that when I connect to the VPN for this particular client it cuts off connection to many of my work resources (Sharepoint, Outlook, Skype, and most importantly Pandora)

YEARS ago, I had a similar issue, and my buddy added a route so that only traffic to their site/server went through the VPN.  Problem is that I have no idea how he did it.  I looked up some stuff on the MS sites and tried to add routes, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's what I have.

```
C:\Users\Dizzy>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 10...fc aa 14 2e 52 b5 ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V
 16...00 ff d9 d6 21 c7 ......TAP-NordVPN Windows Adapter V9
 14...00 00 00 05 5c 8e ......ASIX AX88772B USB2.0 to Fast Ethernet Adapter
 32...........................Blackhawk
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================
```

I used "route -p" to try to add a persistent route, which is what I thought I needed.  When connected the server IP I connect to is 172.17.15.243.
So now I have this:

```
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
    172.17.15.243    255.255.255.0         On-link        1
      172.17.15.0    255.255.255.0         On-link        1
===========================================================================
```

That doesn't seem to work as I am still unable to access Skype or Pandora.

At this point I don't know if I set something up incorrectly, or what.  One thing I did notice is that last night the interface was #29, and now it's #32

Oh, I have Windows 10 Pro, and I have Cisco Connect installed from the MS Store, so it uses Windows to manage the VPN.

NOT Connected to the VPN I have:

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 10...fc aa 14 2e 52 b5 ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V
 16...00 ff d9 d6 21 c7 ......TAP-NordVPN Windows Adapter V9
 14...00 00 00 05 5c 8e ......ASIX AX88772B USB2.0 to Fast Ethernet Adapter
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.86.1    192.168.86.37     35
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
     192.168.86.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.86.37    291
    192.168.86.37  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.86.37    291
   192.168.86.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.86.37    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.86.37    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.86.37    291
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
    172.17.15.243    255.255.255.0         On-link        1
      172.17.15.0    255.255.255.0         On-link        1
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
 14    291 fe80::/64                On-link
 14    291 fe80::c86d:557e:caf3:da69/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
 14    291 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

CONNECTED to the VPN I have:

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 10...fc aa 14 2e 52 b5 ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V
 16...00 ff d9 d6 21 c7 ......TAP-NordVPN Windows Adapter V9
 14...00 00 00 05 5c 8e ......ASIX AX88772B USB2.0 to Fast Ethernet Adapter
 32...........................Blackhawk
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.86.1    192.168.86.37   4260
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link    172.17.101.209     56
      65.70.114.5  255.255.255.255     192.168.86.1    192.168.86.37   4516
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
      172.17.15.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    172.17.101.209     56
    172.17.15.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    172.17.101.209    311
   172.17.101.209  255.255.255.255         On-link    172.17.101.209    311
     192.168.86.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.86.37   4516
    192.168.86.37  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.86.37   4516
   192.168.86.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.86.37   4516
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.86.37   4516
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    172.17.101.209     56
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.86.37   4516
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    172.17.101.209    311
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
    172.17.15.243    255.255.255.0         On-link        1
      172.17.15.0    255.255.255.0         On-link        1
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
 14    291 fe80::/64                On-link
 14    291 fe80::c86d:557e:caf3:da69/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
 14    291 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

This is on my desktop so it doesn't need to be a portable solution, and I only need to access 1 resource while connected to the VPN.  When I ping it, the IP address is 172.17.15.243
When I do a NSLookUp I get 192.168.86.1
How do I find the LAN Gateway to use when I add the route?  I used 0.0.0.0 but I'm not sure that's correct.

I'm fairly tech minded, but this level of networking has always given me trouble.

Comment: FWIW the `IP` you added was *technically* already on the same network you were on. As it contained the same *netmask* (`255.255.255.0`). You're probably going to need to add a *separate* network. By either "subing"  your current network, or adding an entirely different network. Keywords for you to search against: `networks`, `netmask`, `gateway`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What created your problem

What is happening here is connecting to the VPN will push a very broad route into your OS's route table. You can run `route print` before and after connecting VPN to see what routes are being added as a side-effect of connecting VPN.

You see that the following combination of routes is added to your route table:

```
===========================================================================
  Network Address          Netmask         Gateway         Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link    172.17.101.209      56
      65.70.114.5  255.255.255.255    192.168.86.1     192.168.86.37    4516
      172.17.15.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    172.17.101.209      56
===========================================================================
```

Other routes are also added. We don't care about those so much.

The first route added says traffic destined for "anywhere" should use the VPN tunnel. Ergo, this a default route. Barring some more specific destination, any traffic leaving your machine will use the VPN gateway. Note there is still the old default route listed in the table the indicates "use the LAN gateway for anywhere", but its metric is higher (worse). That route is no longer preferred.

The second route added punches a hole that says traffic destined for the public IP of the VPN server should use the old gateway. Note that even though the metric is higher, the route is more specific. The netmask `255.255.255.255` means "for this IP address only". Specificity takes precedence over metric.

The third route that was added is a specific IP range that should use the VPN gateway. Given that the VPN gateway is already the default route, this is redundant information. I don't really know why this was added, but I can guess the IT administrator for the VPN service probably added this manually because of some specific issue encountered by some user(s).

Other routes that were added include new default multicast (224.0.0.0) and broadcast (*.*.*.255) routes. There are also routes added for your machine's own IP address on every network. Not sure why those are needed; it could be a Windows thing.

#### Technically, what is the problem?

These routes tell your computer to send via the VPN tunnel ALL traffic except for the VPN tunnel itself and the traffic for the immediate local LAN. This is done because the VPN gateway can (and often needs to) route your traffic to more subnets in the remote intranet (as distinct from internet). For example, when connecting VPN your computer is be issued an IP address of 172.17.101.209/24. The mail servers on the remote network might be located at 172.17.15.4/24, Sharepoint at 172.17.7.16/24, Skype at 172.17.55.27/24, etc. These are all on separate subnets from your VPN IP and only the VPN gateway can route traffic to these machines. Rather than push each IP or subnet individually to your route table (e.g. your route to 172.17.15.0), it is easier for corporate IT to set/override the default route of all traffic to use VPN and let the VPN gateway figure out how to connect you to all the subnets you want to reach.

Pushing a new default route to VPN clients becomes an issue when those clients also have resources in their local network they are trying to access. The same examples apply: mailservers, internal websites, Skype, etc. You need your local gateway to reach these.

#### Theoretically, how do we resolve this problem?

We need to know which networks are on which gateway. If we try to use a gateway for a network that isn't routable from that gateway, we will get a `DESTINATION NOT REACHABLE` response. If we use the remote gateway to reach our local SharePoint server, we get that response. This puts us in a tricky position of manually adding routes to our OS's route table telling it which gateway to use for different IP ranges. This can be seriously temperamental, especially in large corporate networks, because both networks may use the same internal IP ranges. Basically, we are in a situation where we pick one of the two gateways to be our default gateway, then we add routes for individual subnets that we need from the other gateway.

#### What command do I run to make this problem go away?

You are right. You run `route -p add` type commands to add the routes for whichever gateway is not your default gateway. It sounds like your colleague decided to use the VPN's gateway as the default gateway, then add routes manually for each local subset you need access to. You can use `nslookup` to find the IP addresses of servers you need from your local LAN, then add the entire subnet that service resides in to your route table.

For example, I would run `nslookup sharepoint.localcompany.com` and get back an IP of 192.168.12.51. I would then run `route -p add 192.168.12.0 mask 255.255.255.0 <LAN-gateway-ip>`.

Hopefully you only need to add one or two subnets to get everything working. Hopefully those subnets are not common (e.g. 192.168.0.0/24, 192.168.0.1/24, or 10.0.0.0/24). See "other problems" below.

#### Edit for new information

Given the IP addresses I am seeing in your route table, I would run this command and see if things worked better. I don't know if interface 10 or 14 is the one you use for LAN, so pick the corresponding number based on your setup.

`route -p add 192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0 0.0.0.0 IF [10/14]`

This command says "Use the gateway learned on the LAN interface for IPs in range 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255". It might break certain things, in which case you can roll it back by swapping `add` for `delete`.

#### Other problems

This entire problem is replicated in the DNS subsystem. You have DNS servers for two different networks and `internal-sharepoint..com` isn't in the remote DNS server. I hate to leave this exercise to the user, but its an entirely separate issue to trap. TL;DR: I believe you rely on 'DNS suffixes' to know which DNS server to use. Please post a separate question if you need help with this.

This isn't portable. You hard coded which subnets to use with which gateways. If you work from home and use your own company's VPN, all those routes you added need to be updated to use your company's VPN gateway instead of whichever gateway you might have used from your office. If you ever roam to another network where you need these subnets to work, these routes need to be removed. Primarily, this is why my response is so long. If you just run the commands you will won't recognize new problems that will only crop up later. When those problems happen, you have to back out or modify these changes you made to your route table.

IP Conflict issues. If you had to add a common subset, you will inevitably/soon run into a situation where you need that subnet to work in both the local and the remote network. I think it is easiest to just accept the inconvenience, remove all manually added routes, and enable/disable VPN as needed to access local/remote services.

Please let me know if this explanation is unclear or if I can explain a part in more detail.

Comment: Great response, and great info.  Unfortunately while I am a techie, networking has always been my downfall, so I couldn't follow you entirely.  I added some details to the bottom of my post, maybe you can help clarify.

Comment: Edited awnser for new information. Try running `route -p add 192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0 0.0.0.0 IF [10/14]`. Pick 10 or 14 depending on which interface you use for LAN.